# troublesome regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

i was hoping someone could help me understand why this happens:

```
    String s = "tbody\n" +"a\n" +"/tbody";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("tbody[^(/tbody)]+/tbody"); 

    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("found: \n\n"+m.group());            
    }
```

Output is:

```
found: 

tbody

a

/tbody
```

But if `String s = "tbody\n" +"ao\n" +"/tbody"` (I added an o after the a) it prints nothing. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

I'm using NetBeans 7.4.

Comment: `[..]` in a regular expression is a *character class* - now you know the name, look it up :) In any case, consider just using a *non-greedy/lazy quantifier*: `tbody(.*?)/tbody` (you may also be interested in *word boundaries*).

Comment: You seem to be trying to figure out how to parse HTML with regular expressions.  This is a non-starter, since HTML is not a regular language.  Please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/18157)

Comment: @JimGarrison i'm not sure what i'm trying to do is parsing. I need to collect info from a specific website, wich lies between those tags.

Comment: You'll be much better off if you use a real HTML parser like JSoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^(/tbody)]` is not what you thought it is.
It does not mean any string which is not `/tbody`.
Instead it negates each char one by one.
Now `/tbody` contains `o` and you added an `o`
(so you have that `o` negated).
That's why it does not match any more.

Try adding `x` instead of `o` and it will keep working
(as `x` is not among the chars you negated).